# Java switch statement using class.getSimpleName() gives Constant express required error

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to use class.getSimpleName() for the expression of a switch however it gives me an error:

> Constant express required

I've seen answers suggesting to change the expression variable declarations to have initializers that are compile-time constant expressions. However, this is not possible in this case.

Is there a way to make a switch using class.getSimpleName() without having to hardcode the class names?

**Example code**

```
public class ClassA {
   public static final String TAG = ClassA.class.getSimpleName();
   ...
}

public class ClassB {
  public static final String TAG = ClassB.class.getSimpleName();
  ...
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
  switch (express) {
     case ClassA.TAG: // Error here
        ...
        break;
     case ClassB.TAG: // and here
        ...
        break;
     default:
        ...
        break;
 }
```

Comment: @Eran This is not problem with the value on which you switch, but the case values themselves.

Comment: @Eran Yes, I'm using java 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a way to make a switch using class.getSimpleName() without having to hardcode the class names?

No. Basically, calling `Class.getSimpleName()` doesn't count as a compile-time constant expression, so it can't be used as a case statement. It would be nice if there were a `nameof(...)` operator as there will be in C# 6, but without that, I don't think you'll be able to use a switch/case without hard-coding the names.